# Java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait() при вызове метода wait() в потоке

Tags: java, android, android-studio, многопоточность, синхронизация

У меня проблема с вызовом метода `wait()` в новом фоновом потоке. Подскажите, как можно исправить код, чтобы убрать ошибку?

Файлы и лог прилагаются:

**Лог:**

```
08-31 20:39:44.745 29803-29803/******* W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
    at com.mathtrainer.superschoolboy.AdditionFragment$18$1.run(AdditionFragment.java:498)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6039)
    at com.mathtrainer.superschoolboy.AdditionFragment$18.run(AdditionFragment.java:493)
08-31 20:39:44.746 29803-29803/com.mathtrainer.superschoolboy W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
    at com.mathtrainer.superschoolboy.AdditionFragment.newforall(AdditionFragment.java:511)
    at com.mathtrainer.superschoolboy.AdditionFragment.onCreateView(AdditionFragment.java:370)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1580)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

**Метод `newforall()`:**

```
private synchronized void newforall(){

    //Остальной код (не относится к проблеме)

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            for(int x = 10; x > 0; x = x - 1) {
                                wait(1000);
                                timerView.setText(Integer.toString(x));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Timer Thread", "Here is an issue!");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    th.run();
}
```

Comment: Зачем Вам `wait()`, да ещё и в UiThread'е? Скорее всего Вашу задачу можно решить по-другому. Почитайте про `android.os.Handler`. Можете описать подробнее чего Вы хотите добиться и возможно Вам здесь подскажут как это сделать лучше.

Comment: Я хочу сделать что-то наподобие таймера, который будет обновлять интерфейс (выводить кол-во оставшихся секунд), но использовать java.util.Timer (т.к. его настройка слишком сложна)

Comment: У Андроида есть класс специально для этой задачи: [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) - в документации есть пример использования.